# Building .net solution in tfs 2017 gives error of dlls reference help required

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

building a solution in TFS 2017, every time I build a solution using build solution step it gives me an error of third-party dll reference, every time I manually need to put the dlls in the agent/work folders on builds server. is there any workaround to successfully build a solution without putting dlls manually..?

Any help is appreciated.

thanks
Kapil

Comment: Are they from NuGets or manually added references? Are they included in source control if latter?

Comment: we have both nugets as well as third-party dll like ajaxtoolkit, i am able to get microsoft dll from nugets but the third-party dlls are the manually added

Comment: @KapilGupta can you build successful now by using the way as huserben suggested?

Comment: yes i can and thanks a lot for the right path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the missing dlls come from a nuget package, make sure to add a nuget restore step before the build step.
If the missing files are a third party dll, check whether they are properly checked into source control and they are downloaded as part of the GetSources step of the build. Check for this the Log of the GetSources step whether it includes those dll's. If they are not there and they are properly in source-control, you probably have missed to map the folder they're in, so the Build will not download it as part of the GetSources step.

Comment: thanks that work, but again there is one doubt, is it a good practice to check-in the dlls in source control..?

Comment: Well if you have another option like nuget, I would definetly go for this. But depending on who provides the third party dll's that's not always possible. In that case I would rather check these files in than relying on the fact that someone put it in the right place on the build server. It simplifies as well the process if someone new wants to start working with the project, as he can just get the latest sources instead of installing dll's into the right place.